# Yii2 - URL for basic application template

Tags: php, yii2

I have just installed the Yii2 Basic Application Template using Composer.

This is now accessible on my localhost machine at the following URL:

`http://localhost/basic/web`

In Yii 1.1, it was possible to access a web application by simply going to :

`http://localhost/basic`

Having done some reading, it appears the only way to achieve the above is to create a new Apache vhosts entry. Whilst this is fine for one or two sites, if like myself you are working on new sites all the time, it is a bid tedious to have to set up vhosts for each and every site.

I have tried creating a `.htaccess` file to redirect all requests to `web/index.php` but this does not work. Is this at all possible to do in Yii2?

Answer (score 0):

Move all the content in the `/basic` folder to eg. `/basic-yii` instead. Then take the `/basic/web` folder (now `/basic-yii/web`) and put all it's content into the `/basic` folder. Then adjust the paths for the `require()` calls in `/basic/index.php` to correctly point to `autoload.php`, `Yii.php` and `web.php`.